# Prove that $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ iff $\frac{d}{c}=\frac{b}{a}$ with this definition...

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, math-history

I need to prove that $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ iff $\frac{d}{c}=\frac{b}{a}$ using this definition (Eudoxus Def.):

$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ iff for any positive integers $p$ and $q$ it holds

(1) $pa>qb$ iff $pc>qd$

(2) $pa=qb$ iff $pc=qd$

(3) $pa<qb$ iff $pc<qd$

My approach has been using algebra to obtain each of the same conditions for $\frac{d}{c}=\frac{b}{a}$ without luck, but I've been using algebra for (2) like this:

If $pa=qb$ then $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{b}{a}$ iff $pc=qd$ then $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{d}{c}$. Therefor $\frac{d}{c}=\frac{b}{a}$.

This is a right approach? How should I faced the other two conditions?

Comment: Your convoluted conditional appears to be trivially true, but It does not rely on $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ being true, so it can't be used to prove that $\frac{d}{c}=\frac{b}{a}$

Comment: Try writing out the conditions for $\frac{d}{c}=\frac{b}{a}$ and comparing them to the conditions for $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$.

Comment: I did what you suggest and they are the same with different positive integers. What I though was maybe trying to prove that the positive integers chosen for the first part are the same for the second one?

Comment: They're the same integers, just swapped around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$.
   Then for any positive integers k and h

(1) ka>hb iff kc>hd

(2) ka=hb iff kc=hd and

(3) ka$<$hb iff kc$<$hd

Flipping the iff statements we get,

(1) kc>hd iff ka>hb

(2) kc=hd iff ka=hb and

(3) kc$<$hd iff ka$<$hb

Flipping the order of the inequalities we get

(1) hd>kc iff hb>ka

(2) hd=kc iff hb=ka and

(3) hd$<$kc iff hb$<$ka

h and k are arbitrary integers so the criteria are true for all integers, so $\frac{d}{c}=\frac{b}{a}$

Comment: I did it pretty much like that. I should have posted my answer. Thank you.